# Change 'Create an Account' text on header.links?

Tags: layout, magento2

Would like to change the "Create an Account" text to "Register" with an image label before the text but I can't update the text with the following modification of *Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml*.

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Register</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" display="false" />
    <!--
    <move element="register-link" destination="header.links"/>
    <move element="header" destination="header.links" before="-"/>
    <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>
    <move element="authorization-link" destination="top.links" after="-"/>
    -->


    <block
        class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
        template="account/link/authorization.phtml" before="register-link"/>
</referenceBlock>
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header">
    <!--
    <arguments>
        <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
    </arguments>
    -->
</block>
```

what's my fault?

Answer (score 8):

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link">
<arguments>
<argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Register</argument></arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

place above code in `/app/design/frontend/vendor/module/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Flush Magento cache...

Comment: What name parameter should be used to change text of Sign In?

Comment: @Moax6629 please look at this StackExchange solution to change **Sign In** text to **Register** since it is done different using a theme **i18n** csv file: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251065/6014

Answer (score 2):

Go to  **app/design/frontend/vendor/module/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

and place below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Register</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```